# Request had insufficient authentication scopes although I am using the scope calendar

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add a new event to a calendar, but I am getting the error that I don't have permission to do that. However, I can get the calendars and the events, because I have read permissions.

My code is this:

```
static string[] ScopesParaModificar = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };

private void SetCredentialParaModificar()
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = "token.json";
        _credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
            ScopesParaModificar,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
    }
}

private CalendarService GetCalendarService()
{
    return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = _credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
}

private void ucBtnCrearEvento_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CalendarService miCalendarService = GetCalendarService();
    IEnumerable<CalendarListEntry> misCalendarios = miCalendarService.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;

    CalendarListEntry miCalendario = misCalendarios.FirstOrDefault(x => string.CompareOrdinal(x.Summary, "TestAGarcia") == 0);

    Event miEventoNuevo = new Event();
    miEventoNuevo.Id = "1";
    miEventoNuevo.Summary = "Esto es Summary 01";
    miEventoNuevo.Description = "Esto es el description";

    Event.CreatorData miCreador = new Event.CreatorData();
    miCreador.DisplayName = "DisplayName of creator";
    miCreador.Email = "email del creador";
    miCreador.Id = "ID creador";
    miEventoNuevo.Creator = miCreador;

    miCalendarService.Events.Insert(miEventoNuevo, miCalendario.Id).Execute();
}
```

Notice that when I set _credential, I am using the array that it uses the scope calendar, that it says that it is what I have to use if I want to modify events.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream)` instead of `FromStream` method. Also try changing your calendar scopes to `static string[] ScopesParaModificar = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, CalendarService.Scope.Calendar_Events};` My assumption is the scopes, because the one you have only allows for calendar changes itself and not the events for that calendar...

Comment: @B'ajj I voted to approve your suggested edit, but I'm really hesitant to approve edit suggestions which manage to misspell "grammar" in the motivation.

Comment: @zaggler I have tried with Load, but it doesn't work. Anyway I was using FromStream because load is deprecated. Also I have tried with the ScopesParaModificar as you suggested but I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried adding ````CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents```` to your scope array  ````ScopesParaModificar```` according to the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService.Scope.html)?